# Clicking KivyMD Check Box deselects any other checked boxes

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I would like the user to be able to select multiple items from a list of check boxes, but for some reason checking a second box deselects the first and I cannot understand why. My code is below:

Python:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBodyTouch
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class LeftCheckbox(ILeftBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    pass 

class CreateWorkoutCustomDialog(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        lifts = ['Bench Press', 'Squat', 'Deadlift', 'Weighted Pull-ups', 'Rows', 'Shoulder Press']
        for lift in lifts:
            self.ids.box.add_widget(CreateWorkoutLiftRow(lift = lift))

class CreateWorkoutLiftRow(MDBoxLayout):
    lift = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lift = kwargs['lift']
    
    def set_icon(self, instance_check):
        instance_check.active = True if instance_check.active == False else instance_check.active == False

class Main2App(MDApp): 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lift_dialog = None
        
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('dialog.kv')
        return Builder.load_file("scratch.kv")

    def show_lift_dialog(self):
        if not self.lift_dialog:
            self.lift_dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Create New Workout",
                type="custom",
                content_cls = CreateWorkoutCustomDialog(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(text="CANCEL"),
                    MDFlatButton(text="OK"),
                ],
            )
        self.lift_dialog.open()
            
Main2App().run()
```

scratch.kv:

```
MDScreen:
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_lift_dialog()
```

dialog.kv:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<CreateWorkoutCustomDialog>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '400dp'

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Workout Title"
        required: True
        id: workout_title

    ScrollView:
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            id: box
            spacing: "12dp"
            
<CreateWorkoutLiftRow>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    ItemConfirm:
        text: root.lift
        on_release: root.set_icon(check)
        size_hint_x: .7
        divider: None

        LeftCheckbox:
            id: check
            group: "check"
            active: True

    CreateWorkoutSetsInput:
        id: input
        hint_text: "# sets"
        size_hint_x: .3
     
<ItemConfirm@OneLineAvatarIconListItem>:
    
<CreateWorkoutSetsInput@MDTextField>:
```

I've reviewed several tutorials and tried my best to understand the documentation but I cannot see where the interaction between discrete check boxes is even happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the result of using `group` with the `CheckBox`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.ToggleButtonBehavior.group).

```
group: "check"
```

Just remove that line in the `kv`.